# VTK and Paraview volume rendering

Tags: 3d, visualization, vtk, paraview

[Paraview](http://www.paraview.org/overview/) is a visualisation application based on VTK library. I have a volume (vti format) that I can visualise it in Paraview and set the color and opacity transfer function. I can also load it into VTK as vtkImageData and render it using the same color and transfer function settings as Paraview, however, I cannot get the same result.
Paraview rendering of the volume:
[image: Paraview visualisation]

VTK rendering of the volume using same settings:
[image: VTK visualisation]

The setting in Paraview:
[image]

The snippet in VTK for setting:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction> compositeOpacity =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkPiecewiseFunction>::New();
compositeOpacity->AddPoint(0.0,0.0);
compositeOpacity->AddPoint(255,1.0);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction> color =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkColorTransferFunction>::New();
color->AddRGBPoint(0.0  , 0.231373, 0.298039, 0.752941);
color->AddRGBPoint(18.62, 0.865, 0.865, 0.865);
color->AddRGBPoint(61.52, 0.9647, 0.639, 0.518);
color->AddRGBPoint(249, 0.705882, 0.01568, 0.14902);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty> volumeProperty =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkVolumeProperty>::New();
volumeProperty->SetScalarOpacity(compositeOpacity); // composite first.
volumeProperty->SetColor(color);

// Visualize
vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmartVolumeMapper> mapper =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkSmartVolumeMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputData(imageData);
mapper->SetRequestedRenderModeToDefault();
```

What can I do in order to have the same rendering in VTK?

Comment: Does changing the upper opacity from 1.0 to something smaller (e.g., 0.2) make the volume rendering from VTK closer to the one from ParaView?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to disable opacity mapping in Paraview.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Sorry, I actually need the VTK to display the same as Paraview, not the other way round. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the blend mode explicitely, for example: 
mapper->SetBlendModeToComposite();

vtkSmartVolumeMapper uses a different mapper depending on the mode you select. See the documentation here:
https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkSmartVolumeMapper.html

I'm using vtkOpenGLGPUVolumeRayCastMapper rather than vtkSmartVolumeMapper and in my apps volume transparencies are displayed correctly.